# Android : how to set <value> of an <entry> of a xml file equal to <string> of strings.xml?

Tags: android, xml

I have a xml file in my xml app folder with entries like this:

```
<defaultsMap>
    <entry>
        <key>latest_gplay_app_version</key>
        <value>5.3</value>
    </entry>
</defaultsMap>
```

I would like to replace `<value>5.3</value>` with something like:

```
 <value>"@string/latest_version"</value>
```

so that the value is automatically set to the latest_version string defined in my strings.xml file

How can I di this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. This is not universal feature - it applies only to resources XMLs (`res/` folder in your project) so you need to read your raw XML, substitute what you need and then use your final XML. Naturally you can substiture with the value read from resources if needed, yet some code is needed anyway.